# Powerpoint vba : How to get a group of shapes by group name

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have group several shapes to a group and give a name to the group.

```
ShapesList("Shape 1", "Shape 2", "Shape 3")

set grp = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlidesName).Shapes.Range(ShapesList).Group
grp.Name = "GroupA"
```

Then I can I get the grp ?

```
set grp = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlidesName).Shapes.Range("GroupA") 'any method to do this?
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `.Range`. Try this

```
Dim grp As Shape

Set grp = ActivePresentation.Slides(SlidesName).Shapes("GroupA")
```